# Error of querying on CodeIgniter using REGEXP with [[:<:]] [[:>:]]

Tags: php, mysql, regex, codeigniter

I got a problem when I querying data on CodeIgniter using `REGEXP` with `[[:<:]]`and`[[:>:]]`.

The system keep adding the space character on the front and the back of the less-than sign.

For example:

```
$this->db->get_where('news', array("News_Tag REGEXP BINARY "=>"[[:<:]]data[[:>:]]"));
```

will become:

```
SELECT * FROM `web_news` WHERE `News_Tag` REGEXP BINARY '[[: < :]]data[[:>:]]'
```

and cause the error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `web_news` WHERE `News_Tag` REGEXP BINARY '[[: < :]]data[[:>:]]' "); <---this one is working right?

Comment: It work, thanks.
But the code should be:
    `$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM web_news WHERE News_Tag REGEXP BINARY '[[:<:]]data[[:>:]]'");`

Comment: is that okay or you want sth else?

Comment: Sometimes 3rd party software hurts instead of helping.  Perhaps it is "protecting" you from something to do with tags.  Put it in a string, then remove extra blanks.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, and solved it by removing the CodeIgniter's Active Records escape from the regex definition.

Just add FALSE as the 3rd param in your get_where clause, and also add single quotes to the expression:

`$this->db->get_where('news', array("News_Tag REGEXP BINARY "=>"'[[:<:]]data[[:>:]]'"), FALSE);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer from `Danyal Sandeelo`, I found the solution that is:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM web_news WHERE News_Tag REGEXP BINARY
'[[:<:]]data[[:>:]]'");
```